# Having issues adding full width slider or image to twitter bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on converting a twitter bootstrap theme into a wordpress theme and adding onto it.

I am having issues adding full width items into the theme. I have tried adding a slider plugin that is set to full width. Although when it is added it goes to a fixed width, the same happens if I add an image aswell. It seems all of the content in my page does this except for my header and footer.

Also it seems every time I add in anything to the page the page/footer gets messed up. I am still learning css though.

I am posting a link to the site to see if anyone can take a look and give me a hand.

http://goo.gl/8JUDA

Comment: You're trying to make the slider's width stretch 100% of the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you contained the element that you want to stretch the size of the window within a `.container` div.

`.container` is used in bootstrap for fixed layouts. Instead try using the `.container-fluid` class.

For example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Read more: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts

Comment: Awesome thank you very much. I am having one issue though. Since I added that in it moved the container down substantially. I tried moving it up with a margin and padding although that isn't working. Could you steer me in the right direction?

Comment: You really shouldn't need to do any custom CSS to get it to look nice. It looks like you're using the layout wrong. You should have a single `.fluid-container` div in your layout (a "container" contains several elements). And within the container you should have `.row-fluid` elements which would contain a "row" of elements.